# jQuery AJAX data to HTML

Tags: ajax, jquery

EDIT: Ok, so the solution i came up with, is basically count the characters and see the difference between the numbers. One headache i had was related with the fact that the .html() didn't showed me the 
 with the slash, instead, 
. Annoying....

```
function verifica(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "html",
    url: 'icallverifica.php',
    data: "valor=0",
    success: function(data) {
        var verificando = $('#results').html();
        var verificandox = (verificando.length);
        var verificador = data.length;
        if(verificandox != verificador){
            $('#results').html(data);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

I'm creating a little script using AJAX that retrieves data from a database. The problem is that I've used `setInterval` and it's refreshing all the time.

I don't have a problem with too many accesses to the database, my problem is that I want the content as static as possible until there are new entries on the database:

```
function verifica() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "html",
        url: 'icallverifica.php',
        data: "valor=0",
        success: function(data) {
            var verificando = $('#results').html();
            if (verificando != "<html>"+data+"</html>") {
                $('#results').html(data);}
            }
    });
}
```

The function changes the `#results` div introducing the database information, the thing is that I don't want to change the div content unless there are any new entries.

What I did was check on the database and compare the previous content on the div, if it's the same, it will not overwrite.

BUT, i can't put data in html format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `success` handler to:

```
success: function(data) {
    var verificando = $('#results').html();
    if (verificando != data) {
        $('#results').html(data);}
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, didn't work, but can see the solution on my post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this instead ?

```
if ( verificando != data ){
    $('#results').html(data); 
}
```

You shouldn't need to concatenate `<html>` to the data while comparing it.

Comment: I tried almost everything, but came up with a different solution. See the first post. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Such comparison is a overkill. You can basically check the ids associated to each result and then just refresh only the part which is new.

May be you can send the ids along with the ajax request itself and then filter out the response and send only which are the new results.

Comment: You are right, not practical, so i came up with a practical solution. See my post.